# Does anyone know why my JTable throws NullPointerException when I set more than 2 columns in my JTable?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable

I did some investigating and it appears the issue is located in the `DefaultTableModel`. Specifically, in the `getColumnClass` method. When I use only 2 columns in the `columnNames` `String` array:

```
(String[] columnNames = {"Icon", "Filename"})
```

Everything works fine. But when I add a third column:

```
(String[] columnNames = {"Icon", "Filename", "Size"}):
```

I start getting the `NullPointerException` error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
package jtablefun;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class JtableFun extends JFrame{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
   new JtableFun().show();
}

public JtableFun(){
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    //String s[] = f.list();




    buildTable();

    pack();

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }

    });

}



public void buildTable(){
             File f = new File("/");
             File[] fl = f.listFiles();

             String fileNames[] = f.list();
             Icon iconArray[] = new Icon[fileNames.length];
            //Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(f);
            for(int i=0; i<fileNames.length; i++){

                iconArray[i] = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(fl[i]);

            }


    String[] columnNames = {"Icon", "Filename", "Size"};


    Object[][] data = new Object[fl.length][(fl.length * 2)];

    for(int row=0; row<fl.length; row++){

         for(int column=0; column<2; column++){
             if(column == 0){
             data[row][column]= iconArray[row];
                     }else if(column == 1){
                        data[row][column]= fileNames[row]; 
                     }else if(column == 3){
                        //data[row][column]= fl[row].length(); 
                     }
         }

    }


            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
    {
        //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
        //  renderers to be used based on Class
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        } 
    }; 
                    JTable table = new JTable( model );
                            table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
    GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
    g.gridx =0;
    g.gridy =0;
    getContentPane().add(table,g);
}
}
```

Comment: `return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();` is dangerous, because if the result of `getValueAt` returns `null` it will generate a `NPE`, you should be returning a concert class type (like `Icon.class`) based on the requested column index. My suspicion is, `iconArray` contains a `null` value

Comment: What would cause getValueAt () to return null? I'm not really sure how getColumnClass works to render an icon or where the column parameter is supplied from.

Comment: getValueAt will return the value associated with the row/column in the data model, if an element is null, then you will get a npe

Comment: Looking at you data, the size column is empty/null

Comment: Ha! Fixed it! You were right @MadProgrammer, 3rd column was null. Thanks!!!